# split the file by their transaction date though ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

By using ADF we unloaded data from on-premise sql server to datalake folder in single parquet for full load.

Then in delta load we are keeping in current day's folder yyyy/mm/dd structur going forward.

But i want full load file also separate it by their respective transaction day's folder.ex: in full load file we have 3 years data. i want data split it by transaction day wise in each separate folder. like 2019/01/01..2019/01/02 ..2020/01/01 instead of single file.

is there way to achieve this in ADF or while unloading itself can we get this folder structure for full load?

Comment: Can we classify documents based on their `last modification date`? Suppose we can classify these files based on this attribute?

Comment: no.its a single file on that we have 2 years data and i want this file partitioned by their transaction column in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi@Kumar AK After a period of exploration, I found the answer. I think we need to use Azure [data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) to achieve that.

1. My source file is a csv file, which contains `transaction_date` column.
   [image]
2. Set this csv as the source in data flow.
   [image]
3. In `DerivedColumn1` activity, we can generate a new column `FolderName` via column `transaction_date`. `FolderName` will be used as a folder structure.
   [image]
4. In `sink1` activity, select `Name file as column data` as File Name option, select `FolderName` column as Column data.
   [image]
5. That's all. These rows of the csv file will be split into files in different folders. The debug result is as follows, :
   [image]

[image]